# Launch a rails server from a ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I need to launch multiple times the same rails application server (webrick) running each one on different port.

I'm trying this:

```
path = '../my_rails_app'
Dir.chdir path
Process.spawn( "rails", "server", "-p #{port}")
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
'spawn': No such file or directory - open
```

I guess because my setup uses RVM and probably ruby don't load the rvm initialize line on `.bashrc`

How I can accomplish this?

Comment: checkout the foreman gem

Comment: I know this is a *weird* setup, and there is not too much sense on launching multiple times the same application but this is what I have to do.

Comment: try run `./bin/rails` or if `fork { Dir.chdir(path) {system "./bin/rails s -p #{port}" } }`

Comment: http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/